# How to avoid blank initialization with taggingjs

Tags: javascript

I have no clue how to resolve this problem.
The TagginJS initializes with a blank tag and I do not know why.

My JS :

```
$(".tagging_class").tagging({
    "tag-char": "@",
    "no-duplicate": true,
    "forbidden-chars": ["?", "$"]
});
```

What I have is a blank tag **[@x]** as first initialized tag

How could I do to avoid it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to resolve my issue, not sure that is the perfect one but it works...

I simply add this instruction

```
$(".tagging_class").tagging("removeAll");
```